# A birational compatification problem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $P_1$ be a projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$, and $Y_1 \subseteq P_1$ be a  codimension $1$ (irreducible) subvariety. Suppose there is a blowdown morphism $Y_1 \to Y_2$.

Then can I find a *projective* variety $P_2$ which contains $Y_2$ and birational to $P_1$?